# What piezo do I need to create electricity by walking?

Tags: piezo, power-generation

What piezo do I need to create electricity by walking? Would any piezo work? Please help me, I need this for a school science project. I could buy a single piezo just to test, but I want to buy them in bulk, so it's faster to build.

Comment: Any piezo will generate electricity providing it is flexed/compressed regularly.

Comment: How much energy do you expect to get from the piezo crystal?  What do you intend to do with the energy?

Comment: JRE, I need enough electricity(around 3.5 volts) to power a simple led.

Comment: What output power do you expect?

Comment: You should investigate "energy harvesting using a piezo" and read what documents google provides you. You should also explain how you will mechanically link walking movement to piezo movement.

Comment: How long should the LED light up?  Do you expect it to blink with each step or to light up constantly?

Comment: 3.5V isn't a measure of energy.  To calculate energy, you need to know the voltage, the current, and the length of time that current flows.  Piezo elements generate high voltage at low current for a very short period of time.  To light an LED for any length of time, you will have to convert the high voltage to a lower voltage and store the energy from individual pulses in a battery or large capacitor.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to light up a 5V LED with footsteps. I figured out a piezo can do the work.

Comment: I need the LED to light up for around 5 seconds.

Comment: IIRC it was done on a dance floor. You won't get the same output.

Answer (score 1):

You could buy the Murata 7BB-20-3 in bulk. Adding the piezo in parallel can increase the output current.

Using the following example, you can generate and store high voltage/low current spikes in the capacitor and you can measure the voltage with a voltmeter. When you have built up enough charge, use the switch to turn on the LED.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS0tQv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I recommend that you look up more information on impedance matching so that you can get a more refined circuit.

Comment: I wonder how many thousand piezos in parallel will be needed to do it.